# avoid jQuery autocomplete to search on input focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Autocomplete is searching on input focus when there is text in it, how to avoid.

Strange behaviour.

Comment: What? That's the exact point to search for possible inputs upon text input! You can set a min-length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not jQuery but browser autocomplite function.

You can simply try to disable it by adding

```
autocomplete="off"
```

to `<input>` `<textarea>` `<form>` etc. so it will look this way:

```
<input autocomplete="off"..../>
```

Note that it may not work under every browser.

Full explanation given on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Answer (score 0):

isn´t it working like this ?

```
<input type="text" name="mytext" autocomplete="off">
```